# I need a software that can find same value between 2 hex file

Tags: hex-viewer

I working on editor 2 hex file, hex number with HxD editor software. I want to find same values between 2. Because have really lot hex number, I need to find a software that help me that job. The software will do:  upload 2 file,or 3 file ( it is not a hex file, I editing those in hex mode, with hex editor, remember ). Then software will automatic find same value between those. That what I need. Thanks.

Comment: The HxD editor website says it has built-in file compare. They als have a [forum](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36917/i-need-a-software-that-can-find-same-value-between-2-hex-file) where you can ask questions

Comment: What OS must it run on? Any price limit?

Comment: window. i can use vmware too.

Comment: or maybe i can copy and paste hex number to a text file. Those will have a clone is text file. But i still don't know any software. word; document,..Any?

Answer (score 1):

[Beyond Comapre](http://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php?zz=features_multifaceted) has hex comparison.

> The hex comapre shows differences byte-by-byte in a typcial hex hump
>   layout.

[image]

Comment: what is this tool BASIC use for, my friend?

Comment: It comapres two files. Tehy can be text files, or image files, or hex files, like you want

Comment: @fastestsuperman Any reason not to buy it? Or did you find another solution?

Comment: I guess we will never know

Comment: No matter how often this question gets bumped to the homepage

Comment: Maybe OP decided that the file comparison capability built into HxD was enough for their needs after all.

Comment: It would have been nice, then, if they posted & accepted their own answer, in order to help others who read the question in future